# Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ be measurable and $f:A \to \Bbb R$. Let $A_0 = \{x \in A : \text{ $f$ continuous at $x$} \}.$ Prove that $f$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ be measurable and $f:A \to \Bbb R$. Denote $A_0 = \{x \in A : \text{ $f$ continuous at $x$} \}.$ Assume that $m(A\setminus A_0) = 0$. Prove that $f$ is measurable.

The map $f$ is measurable if $f^{-1}[V]$ is measurable for any open $V \subset \Bbb R$. Now since $A$ is measurable from Caratheodory’s criterion we have that $$m(A)=m(A\cap A_0) = m(A \setminus A_0)=m(A \cap A_0).$$

So the set $m(A \cap A_0)$ is measurable(?). Now let $V$ be open subset of $\Bbb R$. The preimage $$f^{-1}[V]=\{x \in A \mid f(x) \in V \}.$$

I have a hunch that $f^{-1}[V]=A \cap A_0$ and if $A \cap A_0$ is measurable then $f$ would be also.

Couple of questions.

$(1)$ does the Caratheodory’s criterion hold for general Lebesgue measure or only for the outer measure? If so then this approach fails...

$(2)$ Does the equality $f^{-1}[V]=A \cap A_0 $ hold? My guess is that this can be derived from continuity of $f$, but not sure.

Comment: What do you mean by the first question? The Caratheodory's criterion is an equivalent criterion of measurability. Your formulation is incorrect too.

Comment: Yes, but the wikipedia article states it only for the outer measure not the general Lebesgue measure. So I’m not sure I can test the measurability of $A \cap A_0$ with it?

Comment: If you want to test the measurability of $A \cap A_0$ using the Caratheodory's criterion, you need to prove that $m^*(B) = m^*(B \cap (A \cap A_0))+ m^*(B \cap(A \cap A_0)^c)$ for **every** $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. The reason why it is only for the outer measure is that $B$ is not required to be measurable. You probably misunderstood the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are equipping $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the set of lebesgue-measurable sets. Let $\mu$ denote the Lebesgue-measure. Since it is complete we obtain for any open set $V\subset \mathbb{R}$ because of $\mu(A\setminus A_0)=0$:
$$ \mu(f^{-1}(V)\cap(A\setminus A_0))=0\implies f^{-1}(V)\cap (A\setminus A_0) \text{ is measurable}$$ due to completeness of the lebesgue-measure. Now we consider
$$f^{-1}(V)\cap A_0 = (f|_{A_0})^{-1}(V)$$
but the map $f|_{A_0}$ is continous by assumption hence $f^{-1}(V)\cap A_0$ is open. The claim now follows by the identity
$$ f^{-1}(V) = (f^{-1}(V)\cap A_0) \cup (f^{-1}(V)\cap (A\setminus A_0)) $$

Comment: $f^{-1}(V) \cap (A \cap A_0)$ is measurable since it’s a subset of $A \cap A_0 $ which has measure zero?

Comment: Yes this is true for regular measures (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure) and the lebesgue measure is regular by construction. Indeed it is the completion of the Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure, second example)